# Factory which creates disposable objects

Tags: c#, factory, disposable

Let's say I have a factory which creates a service based on a disposable resource.
I think the first solution is the cleanest one but I can't figure it out how to dispose 'instance' in my case.
The second one would be a solution but that could be called a factory? I don't think so because that holds a proper resource.
Furthermore 'DisposableIOResource' is that kind of service which is hard to create and that you just want to hide behind a factory.
Is there a good pattern to solve this scenario?
Below my two draft snippets.

```cs
// first solution
public class ServiceFactory
{
    public Reader CreateReader(string configuration) 
    {
        var instance = new  DisposableIOResource(configuration);
        return new Reader(instance);
    }
}

// first solution - use case
var serviceFactory = new ServiceFactory();
var reader = serviceFactory.CreateReader(configuration)
reader.DoSomething(); // NOTE! How do I dispose 'instance'???


// second solution
public class ServiceFactory : IDisposable
{
    private readonly DisposableIOResource _instance;

    public ServiceFactory(string configuration)
    {
        _instance = new  DisposableIOResource(configuration);
    }

    public Reader CreateReader() 
    {
        return new Reader(_instance);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _instance.Dispose();
    }
}

// second solution - use case
using(var serviceFactory = new ServiceFactory(configuration))
{
    var reader = serviceFactory.CreateReader():
    reader.DoSomething();
}
```

--- Edit
I ended up whit another solution maybe a cleaner one:

```cs
public interface IDisposableIOResourceFactory
{
    DisposableIOResource Create();
}

public class DisposableIOResourceFactory : IDisposableIOResourceFactory
{
    private readonly string _configuration;
    public DisposableIOResourceFactory(string configuration) 
    {
       _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public DisposableIOResource Create()
    {
        return new  DisposableIOResource(this._configuration);
    }
}

// third solution

public class ServiceFactory
{
    public Reader CreateReader(IDisposableIOResourceFactory resourceFactory) 
    {
        return new Reader(resourceFactory);
    }
}

public class Reader
{
   public Reader(IDisposableIOResourceFactory resourceFactory) {}

   public void DoSomething()
   {
      using var resource = resourceFactory.Create();
      // work on resource
   }
}

// first solution - use case
var serviceFactory = new ServiceFactory();
var resourceFactory = new DisposableIOResourceFactory();
var reader = serviceFactory.CreateReader(resourceFactory);
reader.DoSomething();
```

Comment: Looks to me that the Reader class should implement IDisposable. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Both are technically factories but your second implementation uses the singleton pattern which is not usually coincided with a factory. I wouldn't focus so much on the labels but rather what the code does for you, and the problems that it solves.

Comment: `using var reader = serviceFactory.CreateReader(configuration);` and then `Reader` is responsible for disposing any of it's internal resources.

Comment: The factory has no way to guess when the consumer is done using the object.  Therefore it must be the Reader class that implements IDisposable.

Comment: @Zoidbergseasharp Let me deep dive into my question. Just think about 'Reader' as an adapter on the DisposableIOResource who does help you read on that resource. Now, the final user of the factory doen't know how to build that resource so you can't just ask him to create DisposableIOResource. In this case the only one who knows how to create it is the factory but in this case "how do you handle this object Dispose"?

Answer (score 2):

Your factory isn't the thing that needs to implement IDisposable. Your Reader does.

This is okay.

```
// first solution
public class ServiceFactory
{
    public Reader CreateReader(string configuration) 
    {
        var instance = new  DisposableIOResource(configuration);
        return new Reader(instance);
    }
}
```

You don't include the class `Reader`

But it should implement IDisposable

```
public class Reader : IDisposable
{
    private readonly DisposableIOResource _instance;

    // Code Here
    public Reader(DisposableIOResource instance) {
        _instance = instance;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
       _instance?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Then when you create one, you put that into a using

```
var serviceFactory = new ServiceFactory(configuration);

using(var reader = serviceFactory.CreateReader()) {
   reader.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: This is only half the story, `Reader` needs to dispose `instance`. Also, I recommend using the updated `using` syntax that has been around since C# 8

Comment: I intentionally omitted the `Reader` disposing the `instance` because that code wasn't included in the original question. But yes that is correct.

Agreed, if possible, use the more recent syntax, but from the question it wasn't clear what language version he was using, so I went with the most compatible.

Comment: @DavidG This is not a question about how to implement IDisposable - theres a billion of those on SO already.  Kaddyuk has answered the core question.  If OP wants to learn about implementing that he can search and will find.

Comment: @Ricibob I'm well aware of that, but OP has specifically asked how to dispose of the inner object, not the `Reader` object.

Comment: Implemented the dispose of instance inside Reader. No need to add the null operator ? if you have nullability turned on, but included for backwards compatibility.